# Plot3D Reader Sample Data

Tags: paraview

Is there a place to find sample CFD data in this format please?

I am trying to create scripts for Paraview to automate files opening and want to use the track function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data from [this article](https://discourse.paraview.org/t/plot3d-format/2511) can be used to test out the file format: